# What type of Sunfish is this?

Tags: fish, fish-identification

I have been fishing in a small lake in Southern Indiana. We’ve caught many Bluegill in the same place and caught this small, I’m assuming young Sunfish today. Is this just a Bluegill that happens to be more colorful because it’s young or is it another type of Sunfish? The closest I can find by researching is maybe a Pumpkinseed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Likely, you are correct and it is a Pumpkinseed Sunfish.  Though, pan fish interbreed and it could be mixed.

The fish identification page (PDF:20/ Printed:37) in the [2019 Michigan Fishing Guide](https://www.michigan.gov/documents/dnr/2019MIFishingGuide-Feb26_647890_7.pdf) has the Pumpkinseed Sunfish looking the closest to your fish.

Warning, the link opens a PDF.